# Programmatically animate Android BrokenView

Tags: android

I was going through some of the awesome Android libraries and I found the Android [BrokenView](https://github.com/zhanyongsheng/BrokenView). It's quite simple to use and uses the touch events to show the broken animation. Here's the code that we're required to add in order to enable a `View` to behave as a `BrokenView`:

```
brokenView = BrokenView.add2Window(context);
listener = new BrokenTouchListener.Builder(brokenView).build();
view.setOnTouchListener(listener);
```

The problem that I've is that I want to perform the broken animation programmatically i.e, without any actual touch events. I tried looking at the source code but couldn't figure out how to achieve that as most of the methods are `protected`.

Any ideas on how can I do that?

Comment: it is in [onTouch()](https://github.com/zhanyongsheng/BrokenView/blob/master/brokenview/src/main/java/com/zys/brokenview/BrokenTouchListener.java). Copy and edit it yourself

Comment: yeah i saw that, but i want to start the animation(`brokenAnim.start();`) programmatically and not with the touch event

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved this using a motion event.  It works, but I'd prefer to call createAnimator() directly, as I don't want the user to be able to trigger the smash via a touch event.

```
long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()+1000;

int[] coords = new int[2];
targetView.getLocationOnScreen(coords);

float x = coords[0] + targetView.getWidth()/2;
float y = coords[1] + targetView.getHeight()/2;

MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
              downTime,
              eventTime,
              MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
              x,
              y,
              0
      );

mBrokenTouchListener = new BrokenTouchListener.Builder(mBrokenView)
        .setEnableArea(mRootView)
        .build();

mBrokenTouchListener.onTouch(targetView, motionEvent);
```

What I'd like to do is this:

```
Point point = new Point((int)x, (int)y);
BrokenConfig config = new BrokenConfig();
brokenView.createAnimator(mFLTargetView, point, config);
brokenView.setEnable(true);
// or 
brokenView.start();
```

but BrokenConfig is package private, and there's no start() method.

HTH